# WebApi routes with same routeTemplate with version constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building an api using WebAPI. What I'm shooting for is creating an external library per version of the API which the WebAPI app will query when registering its routes in `WebApiConfig`

**Example:** `Api.v1` and `Api.v2`

---

They will share similar functionality but based on `version` passed in the header it will choose the proper API Version:

`/{controller}/{action}` - `HTTP-HEADER: version=1` maps to `Api.v1.Controller/Action`

`/{controller}/{action}` - `HTTP-HEADER: version=2` maps to `Api.v2.Controller/Action`

---

The goal is to avoid prefixing `/{ver}/{controller}/{action}`. I know that having `routeTemplates` with the same value is not supported, but I thought I could bind the route to a specific namespace and a constraint might help settle which is matched:

```
namespace Api.v1
{
    public static class Routing
    {
        public static void MapRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            IHttpRoute r = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new 
                {
                    id = RouteParameter.Optional, 
                    namespaces = new string[] { "Api.v1.Controllers" } 
                },
                constraints: new VersionConstraint(2)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class VersionConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    int _version;
    public VersionConstraint(int version)
    {
        _version = version;
    }

    public bool Match(
        HttpContextBase httpContext, 
        Route route, 
        string parameterName, 
        RouteValueDictionary values, 
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        int version;
        int.TryParse(httpContext.Request.Headers["version"], out version);
        return version == _version;
    }
}
```

Attempting to inject the `namespaces` for each route hasn't really helped either. The `DataTokens` property is null and readonly.

---

**Any idea how to do what I'm doing? Any way to have the same route map to different controllers of the same name but with different functionality and namespace?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [Versioning ASP.NET Web API Services Using HTTP Headers](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/versioning-asp-net-web-api-services-using-http-headers/), this appears to answer your question on how to route based on the precense of HTTP headers.

You replace the default controller selector with a custom [IHttpControllerSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944864%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) that selects the correct controller based on the HTTP header.

Comment: well... I have no idea why this didn't come up in my searches, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: using the new attribute routing in Web API v2 you can also use URL based routing, just introduce version in RoutePrefix attribute (for the whole controller) or at action level using the Route attribute

Comment: That only prefixes all the routes for the methods in the controller. The default implementation of IHttpControllerSelector doesn't differentiate between two controllers with the same class name (which of course are in different namespaces). You still need a custom IHttpControllerSelector implementation.

Comment: hi! i already using the web api version via Header. my problem is that how can we separate or group it in Swagger UI? im using net framework 4.7 . please need your guys help